# Bluez-5.37 installation instructions

Tags: bluez

I want to install Bluez-5.37 in my ubuntu 15.10, but I don't know the instructions and I couldn't find it, so please could you tell me about these instructions?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal `sudo apt-get install bluez`

Comment: thanks, it's working, another question please .. actually I want to use it to simulate the transmission with Bluetooth, would you tell me if I need to another packages and how to use Bluez in the simulation?

Comment: 15.10 includes bluez 5.35, not 5.37. @HafsaSedrati please ask separate questions for different topics. Ask Ubuntu is a question/answer site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Sorry, it's ma fault